# Can't take data from props

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with the `prop`. Below is my code and I don't understand why when I'm rendering paragraph with `{this.props.name}`, it doesn't show the name from `props`. It may be a stupid question but I've just started my adventure with `React` so I need your help.

```
class CardGenerator extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Name/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Name extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <p>{this.props.name}</p>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( <CardGenerator name='David'/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not passing the props to Name component. You are passing the prop name to `CardGenerator` component there it will be available by `this.props.name`. To access that inside Name component you need to pass the value to Name component again.

Use this:

```
class CardGenerator extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Name name={this.props.name}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Name extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <p>{this.props.name}</p>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( <CardGenerator name='David'/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Check the working example:

```js
class CardGenerator extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Name name={this.props.name}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Name extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <p>{this.props.name}</p>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( <CardGenerator name='David'/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Right :) I was so close. Thanks, Mayank!

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `name` to the `CardGenerator` component, but then the `CardGenerator` component is not passing the `name` to the `Name` component.